How to use OpenSSH's ssh-add successfully?
After creating a new keypair [.ssh\id_ed25519] with ssh-keygen -t ed25519, upon trying to add it into ssh-agent, I receive an invalid format error:
$ ssh-add .\.ssh\id_ed25519

  Could not add identity ".\.ssh\id_ed25519": invalid format

How would we add the newly created key to ssh-agent. or how should the keypair be created? 

Get-Service ssh-agent returns:
Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  ssh-agent          OpenSSH Authentication Agent

The version is

OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2

The created key looks like this:
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAAAMwAAAAtzc2gtZW
QyNTUxOQAAACChXAqaqjUrYwocYrfHz6jkBBEwHI7hncxntU0sokqdUwAAAJgApiyFAKYs
hQAAAAtzc2gtZWQyNTUxOQAAACChXAqaqjUrYwocYrfHz6jkBBEwHI7hncxntU0sokqdUw
AAAEAoHyHZAAsEu714nPY1c39gol9ucWF9xNt+2JppxOtoDqFcCpqqNStjChxit8fPqOQE
ETAcjuGdzGe1TSyiSp1TAAAAEWpvaGFubmVzQHdzLXN0dWR5AQIDBA==
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----

un and reinstall
Did a
Remove-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0

and a
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0

To make sure the proper versions are installed.

What version of OpenSSH is installed [ssh -V], and how was it installed? I can't replicate on version: OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1

This is a well known issue and is a file formattng problem. If you want additional help you will have to provide additional details. I can't answer the question with the current details

@theking2 - You really should seek to update OpenSSH. OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1 is several years old at this point. You should also make sure that the public and private key do not have the same filename. If that is your actual private key you will want to scrap that once you figure out the problem. You have to update Windows to the current version in order to get the current version of OpenSSH or update it manually.

Add a new line after -----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----

@Ramhound will try, sounds promissing
